# Writing graph to file do not keep vertices names

Tags: r, igraph

When I tired to write a graph to file, the output file do not preserve vertices names.
Here is the code:

```
edgelist = read.csv("test.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")
g = graph.edgelist(as.matrix(edgelist),directed=FALSE)
V(graph)$name <- V(graph)
graph  <- delete.vertices(graph, which(degree(graph) < 1))
write.graph(g, "temp.txt", "edgelist")
```

test.csv:

```
1,11
1,22
2,11
2,33
3,22
3,33
4,44
```

temp.csv:

```
0 4
0 5
1 4
1 6
2 5
2 6
3 7
```

Comment: The "edgelist" format does not use vertex names. Use another format, or write it by hand, i.e. query the named using `get.edgelist` and then use `write`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "edgelist" format is always numeric, so it does not use vertex names. If you want to keep the names use another format, e.g. `ncol`:

```
g <- graph.formula(a-b-c)
write.graph(g, format="ncol", file="test.ncol")

g2 <- read.graph("test.ncol", format="ncol")
str(g2)
# IGRAPH UN-- 3 2 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
# + edges (vertex names):
# [1] a--b b--c
```

Btw. when you do

```
V(graph)$name <- V(graph)
```

that is not the best, because many igraph functions assume that vertex names are characters, and `V(graph)` is numeric. So do

```
V(graph)$name <- as.character(V(graph))
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your code.
I tried it on the data provided in the example above, and I got :At rinterface.c:1225 : Attribute is not character, Invalid value
What works with me is "graphml" format, it looks like it considers nodes' name.

Comment: See my edits, `V(g)$name` is not of type character, that is causing problems sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Gabor Csardi other answer on a manual export using `get.edgelist` with `write` (I used ncolumns=2) did give me strange results: Many edges were somehow duplicated and distorted computation.
I specifically needed to transfer between R - igraph and Python - networkX
The common format that I used was "graphml"
I export using R:
`write_graph(igraphNetwork, paste0("edgelist/",filename,".graphml"), format = "graphml")`

and import using Python:
`G = nx.read_graphml(path)
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'name'))`

When I re-import to R I make sure that all label nodes match up and checked with a simple degree centrality comparison that it all works fine. I use reticulate package to communicate between R and Python.

Answer (score -1):

The option of as.character does not work for me. The solution I found was:

```
V(graph)$id = V(graph)$name
```